# Restart uwsgi only if config is valid

Tags: uwsgi, systemd

I would check the uwsgi config before restarting it, because if it is not valid, it should give warning and does not restart.

1) Can i solve this with writing [some kind of plugin](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/WritingPlugins.html?highlight=plugin) or using [hook](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Hooks.html)?
I've found a phase (`as-user-atexit`) to which i can attach a hook (`exec` some kind of shell commands), but i don't see how can i prevent restarting.

2) Or should i solved this on level [overwriting systemd unit script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37630019/2553200)?

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check this http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FallbackConfig.html for an alternative approach